# Как использовать ресурсы приложения C#, csc.exe?

Tags: c#

Скомпилировал программу на C# через csc.exe, вместе с ресурсами, вот так:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe test.cs /res:txte.txt

Как мне вывести текст из этого файла в консоль?
И как мне запустить файл .exe, который тоже добавлю в ресурсы?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ты хочешь, чтобы выводила программа написанная в test.cs?

Comment: Да, что бы программа в test.cs выводила весь текст из txte.txt

Comment: Да-да спасибо всем знатокам за помощь! :)
Сделаю через ResourceManager

Answer (score 1):

Так как в качестве параметра передается текстовый файл, а не файл ресурса, получить его содержимое в программе можно с помощью метода [`GetManifestResourceStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=netframework-4.8). Прочитав полученный поток в качестве строки можно вывести полученную строку на экран.

Пример:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(). // получаем текущую сборку
            GetManifestResourceStream("txt.txt"))) // получаем ресурс по имени файла "txt.txt"
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd()); // читаем все из потока и сразу выводим в консоль.
        }
    }
```

---

В случае если в ресурсах будет исполняемый файл, самый простой способ выполнить его - это сохранить его в файл и запустить с помощью [`Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8)